# If an object in free-fall is moving upward, the object's velocity is decreasing. Does this mean that the acceleration is -9.8 m/s/s?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, kinematics, acceleration, conventions

I have a problem (that I am not asking you to solve) where it takes $4s$ for an object to travel upward to its maximum height, and we have to determine how far the object travelled.  If the acceleration of gravity is $9.8\,\rm ms^{-2}$ downward, does that mean that the object's acceleration is $-9.8\,\rm ms^{-2}$?

Comment: It totally depends on the direction you chose positive.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That depends on your axis. A **sign** is nothing but a mathematical tool showing direction according to an **axis**, which is also just a mathematical tool. Without an axis, signs don't mean much.

- So, is the axis pointing upwards? Then the downwards-pointing acceleration is negative, yes. Also, the velocity is positive while pointing upwards, so until the top. Velocity is negative when directed downwards, so after reaching the top.
- If you flipped the axis to point downwards instead, then all - both acceleration and velocity - would have opposite signs of that mentioned above.

When ever a direction is *opposite to the axis direction*, then a negative sign is added. And that is all the negative sign tells us: that the direction is opposite to the chosen positive axis direction.

Before an axis is defined, it doesn't make much sense to talk about signs.

Answer (score 1):

The kinematic equations of constant acceleration which you will use to solve your problems are relationships between components of vector quantities.

Assume that you define unit vector up $\hat u$ which in effect is you defining up as positive because a vector quantity in the down direction will have a component up is positive.

Suppose in your example you wanted to evaluate the initial velocity using the equation $v_{\rm f}\,  \hat u= v_{\rm i} \vec u+ a\,\hat u\,t$ where $v_{\rm f}, \, v_{\rm I}$ and $a$ are the components of the final velocity, initial velocity and the acceleration of the unit vector up $\hat u$.

Putting values into the equation gives the answer $0\,\hat u = v_{\rm i}\, \hat u +(-10\,\hat u)\, 4 $ to give an initial velocity of $+40\,\hat u$.
So the initial speed was $40$ in the upward direction.

However once you understand what is going on you would decide on a unit vector in the down direction $\hat d$ but instead of writing the kinematic equation as $v_{\rm f}\,  \hat d= v_{\rm i} \vec d+ a\,\hat d\,t$ you would write it as $v_{\rm f}= v_{\rm i} + a\,t$ knowing that $v_{\rm f}, \, v_{\rm i}$ and $a$ are components of the final velocity, initial velocity and acceleration of the unit vector, $\hat d$.

Putting in values $0=v_{\rm i} = (+10)\, 4$ gives $v_{\rm f} = -40$ which you interpret as a component of velocity of $-40$ in the $\hat d$ direction or as a speed of $40$ in the $-\hat d$ direction ie upwards.

So the final velocity does not depend on you initial choice of making up or down the positve direction.